# Constraint controls greyed out in Xcode (pinning toolbar to bottom)

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

I have a toolbar that I want to pin to the bottom. I was trying to use Storyboard rather than code to do it.

[image]

When I command + drag from the toolbar to the controller, all I get is a delegate option rather than the option to pin to each other.

[image]

How do I add constraints to pin this toolbar to the bottom of the view controller?

Here's my updated view controller flow. Not sure if I need the second navigation controller.

[image]

Comment: I was recently creating a project in which I wanted to make a tableview+toolbar combo. It didn't work unfortunately, I'm not sure if it's not allowed or not, but what I did was I made a tab bar controller first and then I placed a tableview controller in one of it's views.

Comment: You can't put a toolbar inside a table view - that is what you have set up, but you mustn't do that. You can have a table view _and_ a toolbar, but not a toolbar inside a table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you want a table view and a toolbar in the same window. The way to set that up in Xcode is to use a navigation interface, because it has a toolbar. You aren't going to be doing any navigating, perhaps, but that's not important. Start with a navigation interface, and have the table view controller as its child (its root view controller). Now configure the navigation view controller so that the navigation bar is not showing but the toolbar is.

(Of course, if you are already *in* a navigation interface, then just show its toolbar and you're there.)

No constraints are involved.

Comment: I have a `Tab controller -> navigation controllers -> table view (root) -> the new navigation controller -> table view (now root)`. Is that okay?

Comment: Do you really mean that the tab controller's children are all navigation controllers? If so, the second table view is already in a navigation controller. So then you don't need the extra navigation controller; the second table view can just show the navigation controller's toolbar as it appears.

Comment: I added a screenshot to make it clear, instead of me poorly explaining

Comment: Perfect-o-rama. And your description meant what I thought it meant! Very good. So my answer remains. In this situation, your second table view controller is in a navigation interface already. So you don't need the second-level navigation controller. The second table view controller can show the toolbar when its view appears, and hide the toolbar when its view disappears; you do not need any other toolbar than the one already being supplied by the navigation controller. Cool, eh?